# Value from button to be set in the next available JTextField?

Tags: java, sqlite, jtextfield

In my app, I need for values from buttons (the value is taken from an SQLite database) to be displayed in one of 13 JTextFields, and they can be in any order. How do I make it possible for the value to be displayed in the next available JTextField, if say the first one is empty?

The only thing I could think of was

```
                            if (textField.getText().isEmpty())
                            {
                          String text = String.valueOf(num);
                            textField.setText(textField.getText() + text);
                            }
```

What should I do next? How should I go around the `else` statement? Should I even use it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `num`?? The value get from button ?

Comment: @JohnJoe, yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that - it indeed is the value from SQL that is received through clicking the button.

Comment: How do I make it possible for the value to be displayed in the next available JTextField, if say the first one is **NOT** empty?

Comment: try my answer..

Comment: Did the answer worked ?

Comment: @JohnJoe, no, unfortunately, it's not working - I can't even locate the problem. Thanks for the answer! I'll try to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,this should be the idea

```
    JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[13];
    firstText.setName("First Text") ;
    .......
    field[0] = firstText;
    field[1] = SecondText; 
    //then add remaining textfields

   for(JTextField txtField : fields) {
   if(txtField.getText().equals("") ) {
          // do whatever you want
  }else{
         // do whatever you want 
     }
}
```